# Which machine learning model should I use on "better of two" comparisons

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

The mathmatical description of my question can be expresses as follows:

Given a function *Y = f(X)*, where *X* is input and *Y* is output.
A total number of *N* points of X is sampled, denoted as *X[0], X[1], X[2] ... X[N-1]* and corespponding *Y[0], Y[1], ... Y[N-1]*. The problem is, we don't know the exact value of *Y* for each *X*, but the comparison between some of the *Y*. A large binary *NxN* matrix is known:

```
[[a00, a01, a02, ...]
 [a10, a11, a12, ...]
 ...
]
```

*a[i,j] = 1* means *Y[i]>Y[j]*, and *a[i, j] = 0* means no comparison is made between *Y[i]* and *Y[j]*.

What machine learning model should I fit on the matrix so that it can give the comparison results of two arbitrary input *X*.

Or I can give a more specific question: The form of function *Y = f(X, a)* is already know, where *a* is the coefficient to be optimized. How can I find the optimal *a* so that as many as possible comparison relationship from the matrix can be satisfied.

The real world question is like this:

I am developing an image analyzing program for focal spot analyzer (which is just a specialized camera) of scientific laser devices. The laser is focus by an off-axis-parabolic mirror (you can just think of it as a convex lens), which requires huge amount of fine tuning to get a better focal spot. The position and rotation of the mirror can be controlled by stepper motors (6 axes in total), and the focal spot can be viewed on a focal spot analyzer. At present, all tuning has to be done manually, and the ultimate goal is to develop an automatic close-loop tunning program.

The current problem for my program is to determine the quality of the focal spot. The camera gives an 2d image of the focal spot, but it is not simple to define a quality function as there are too many aspect of a focal spot to consider (the waist radius, peak strength, elilipticity, etc). The usually manually workflow is to slightly change one axis of the mirror and see if the focal spot improves over the previous one. This has to be repeated many times every few days, so a lot of comparisons are made. These comparisons are done by human, and I want to train my program to be able to compare like human does. The tuning program is expected to tune like a human too: It tries chaning one axis of the mirror, compare the new focal spot to the previous one, and if it's better, continue changing the same axis, and if it's worse, reverse the change or switch to another axis.

As a backup resort, I developed some mathmatical models to determine the quality based on waist radius(*r*), peak strength(*I*), elilipticity(*e*) and so on. For example an simple model is the linear combination of the three:

```
y = w1*r + w2*I + w3*e
```

But the optimal value of *w1, w2, w3* has to be determined. Using the comparison results by human, I want to find the optimal *w1, w2, w3* so that as many as possible comparison relationship can be satisfied.

I have looked into the algorithms provided by scikit-learn and some other libraries, but it looks like regressions work on exact value of Y, not the comparison relationship between them. So is there a machine learning model avaliable for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923596512000033) shows work on how "to design full-reference image quality assessment algorithm" with machine learning , it can probably help you to figure out how to use your data and how to define what features make your image better than the other one (in this case they use SVM).

I think [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/) could also be adapted to you purpose since CNNs are particularly good to process images (detect features, classify...). So I suggest you read about it.

The amount of data that you have and you can have (with data augmentation) can be a criterion of which option will be the best for you.

I hope this will help you and that your project will be successful.